# Getting UTC time as time_t

Tags: c

I am trying to get UTC time as `time_t`. 
Code below seems giving it correct but surprisingly prints local time only:

```
time_t mytime;

struct tm * ptm;

time ( &mytime ); // Get local time in time_t

ptm = gmtime ( &mytime ); // Find out UTC time

time_t utctime = mktime(ptm); // Get UTC time as time_t

printf("\nLocal time %X (%s) and UTC Time %X (%s)", mytime,  ctime(&mytime), utctime, ctime(&utctime));
```

As we can see values of `mytime` and `utctime` we get are different.
However, when passed as parameters to `ctime` it converts them to same string.

> Local time **55D0CB59** (Sun Aug 16 23:11:45 2015) and UTC Time **55D07E01**
>   (Sun Aug 16 23:11:45 2015)

Comment: The ctime result is a static variable.  Do not use ctime twice in the same print statement.  Do it in two separate print statements.

Comment: @cup: That was the whole story :) Culprit `ctime` returns static. Please can you post that as answer. Thanks a lot for pointing out!

Comment: Please do not "update" your question to contain the answer. You are free, of course, to add your working solution as a separate asnwer.

Comment: time() gets the value in the system clock.  gmtime() is expecting the parameter to be UTC.  If your system clock is already local time, rather than UTC time, then the value from time() needs to be adjusted from local to UTC.

Comment: then the 'time' related functions return a pointer, it is a 'common' statically allocated struct.  So the next call to a 'time' related function will overwrite that data.  Suggest always copying the data to a locally defined struct so it will not be corrupted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ctime result is a static variable. Do not use ctime twice in the same print statement. Do it in two separate print statements.

If ctime is replaced with asctime, the same problem will arise as asctime also returns the result as a static variable.

Answer (score 6):

By definition the C `time()` function returns a `time_t` epoch time in UTC.  So the code commented "//get the local time in time_t" is really getting UTC already, and the comment is incorrect.

From the Linux man-page:

> **time_t time(time_t *tloc);**
>   time() returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (**UTC**).

Giving the code:

```
#include <time.h>

...

time_t utc_now = time( NULL );
```

Comment: According to cplusplus.com this is incorrect. Quoting from https://cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/ (shortened): "value returned generally represents number of seconds since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC (i.e., the current unix timestamp). Although **libraries may use a different representation of time**. Portable programs should not use the value returned by this function directly"

Comment: @Raven - The Linux and Solaris man pages beg to differ.  So as long as it's returning a `time_t`, it doesn't matter what time_t is implemented as.

Comment: Solaris is also Unix, is it not? It seems like the behavior described in your answer is guaranteed on Unix systems, but it is not required by the C standard and therefore is not (strictly) portable.

Comment: @Raven - Maybe.  My understanding of the text you quoted is that libraries *may* use a different representation of time inside the `time_t`, but it's *still is* a `time_t`.   In any event, I don't trust cplusplus.com, but if you can refer me to something in ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C17) I'll happily edit my answer.  But I can't find a copy of that which doesn't require $$$.

Comment: I don't have the standard at hand either (and even if I had, I'm not sure if I was capable enough to read it properly xD). My main intent was not for you to change your answer but to essentially add a note for future visitors, that this behavior _might_ not be universally portable ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what the [documented](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ctime/) behavior is supposed to do:

> Interprets the value pointed by timer as a calendar time and converts it to a C-string containing a human-readable version of the corresponding time and date, **in terms of local time**.

You probably want to use [`asctime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/asctime/) instead.

Comment: I am passing two different parameters to same function `ctime` but it is producing different results. There is no way for `ctime` to understand what time zone I've passed time for. What documentation talks is representation after it converts the input parameter.

Comment: Anyway I found the root cause. It was `ctime` function that returns static string causing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

`ctime` function returns a C string containing the date and time information in a human-readable format.

To get time in UTC you can use `gettimeofday()`  (for Linux)-

```
  struct timeval ptm;
  gettimeofday(&ptm,NULL);
  long int ms = ptm.tv_sec * 1000 + ptm.tv_usec / 1000;
```

And you can see function [`GetSystemTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390(v=vs.85).aspx) in  for windows.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Whatever you mentioned might be correct but I am looking for to use ANSI C library functions preferably. Anyway I found the root cause. It was `ctime` function that returns static string causing this problem.

Comment: This gets the UTC time since epoch? I am just getting a small number, I think it is since the time I turned of my device.